# How do I go about getting CSA certification for a Low Voltage (< 5V) electronic device?

Tags: low-voltage, certification

I have a low voltage home automation device that takes in sensor data and transmits uses it to control electrical switches in a house. Example: The device consists of a microntroller and relays. It takes input data from an (external) temperature sensor, a microcontroller processes the information and controls a relay that in turn controls a light switch in a home. The device is powered by a certified 5V power supply (wall adapter).

I need to get CSA approval for my device. How do I go about doing this?

The CSA groups website was not very helpful with this..

Thanks!

Comment: They surely have contact information

Comment: http://www.csagroup.org/contact-us/   where in the world are you ?  looks like you want client services.

Answer (score 4):

You make contact with their engineers regarding your requirements- the device specifications and the standards it is supposed to meet, submit what they require for testing, and hand over a moderate size pile of money. If iterations are required, the pile gets higher. Other testing companies can test to CSA standards, just as CSA can test to UL or other standards.

There may be inspections of the production facilities required. Listed devices for the relay and power supply and PCB will help reduce the cost.

Your device is not a 5V-only device since it controls the mains. An insulation failure could expose the user to potentially (pun intended) deadly voltages and currents, for example through the power cord. Probably it could represent a fire hazard under some conditions.

Comment: thank you! the note about the device not being 5V-only is very helpful.

Comment: The insulation failure you mentioned: wont I be covered for that if I use Listed relays to control the mains?

Comment: No, the relay may be listed as a component but you want a product listing. For example, a listed relay could be put on a PCB with insufficient creepage between coil and contact, in a flammable case, or using wire that has inappropriate insulation.